# how to save an entire object in a variable on a kendo autocomplete selection

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui, datasource

i need help about a kendo autocomplete widget...
Maybe this is a stupid question, but i just can't reach the solution!!!
My kendoAutoComplete widget, gets data from a c# webservice:

```
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
 [WebMethod]
    public string getComuniList()
    {
        using (PrintInvoicesDataContext context = new PrintInvoicesDataContext())
        {
            List<comuni_italia> comuni = new List<comuni_italia>();
            comuni = context.comuni_italia.ToList();

            var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comuni, Formatting.Indented);
            return jsonStr;
        }

    }
```

this method returns a long object array like this:

```
[  {id_comune: 1, des_comune: "Milano", cod_comune: "A130", cap_comune: "64022"},
   {id_comune: 2, des_comune: "Torino", cod_comune: "A131", cap_comune: "64100"},
   ....
]
```

so, when i choose an item into the kendo autocomplete widget, on the select event, i need to save the whole selected object in a variable.

```
var comuneAutoComplete = $("#comune_w").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 3,
    dataSource: dataSource,
    placeholder: "Inserisci comune...",
    dataTextField: "des_comune",
    dataValueField: "id_comune"
}).data("kendoAutoComplete").bind("select", function (data) {
    //here i want to save the object
    var comune = ????????
});
```

so that i could get fields values like this:

```
var id_com = comune.id_comune;
var des_com = comune.des_comune;
..........
```

this is the model of the datasource:

```
model: {
    fields: {
        id: "id_comune",
        id_comune: { type: "string" },
        des_com: { type: "string" },
        des_prv: { type: "string" },
        des_reg: { type: "string" },
        cod_com: { type: "string" },
        cod_prv: { type: "string" },
        cod_res: { type: "string" }
    }
```

Is it possible??
hope someone can help me!
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the data from the `dataSource` for the selected item is:

```
var comuneAutoComplete = $("#comune_w").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 3,
    dataSource: dataSource,
    placeholder: "Inserisci comune...",
    dataTextField: "des_comune",
    dataValueField: "id_comune"
}).data("kendoAutoComplete").bind("select", function (data) {
    //here i want to save the object
    var comune = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    ...
});
```